# How to make code which overwrites smaller answers with a bigger one?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
my_list = [1, 3, 5, 6, 10, 40, 2, 3, 9, 80, 23, 22]

def multiplied128 ():
    for num in my_list:
        val = num
        ans = val*128
        highest = (ans)
        if ans > highest:
            highest = ans
        return(highest)

print(multiplied128())
```

I need to have code where if the answer is greater than the answer already stored in highest, it is overwritten. With the final return being just the highest result, in this case it would be the 11th result.

Comment: What do you mean by the 11th result?

Comment: Declare the variable `highest` outside the `for` loop?

Comment: `highest = (ans)` is equal to `highest = ans`, so you basically compare `ans` with itself..

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this function? If you want the maximum integer from this list, you could just use the `max` function, because if you multiply a number by some value, it's precedence relative to the other values will not change. According to my current understanding, if you want to multiply the values by 128, and then find the maximum value (which is pointless), this could work :- `return int(max(map(lambda x: x * 128, my_list)) / 128)` or if you want the value multiplied by 128, `return int(max(map(lambda x: x * 128, my_list)))`

Answer (score 0):

To find the highest number you should create a variable to store the highest result so far and compare to it every new result.
Here I defined the variable `highest`  before the loop and set its value to `0`
I'm not sure why you're doing the multiply by 128 but I left it there for you.

```
my_list = [1, 3, 5, 6, 10, 40, 2, 3, 9, 80, 23, 22]


def multiplied128():
    highest = 0
    for num in my_list:
        ans = num*128
        if ans > highest:
            highest = ans
    return highest


print(multiplied128())
```

BTW, the same result can be achieved with the built-in function `max`:

```
print(128*max(my_list))
```

Comment: offering an explanation of what was wrong in OPs original attempt would be a good addition to this answer

Comment: added an explanation

Answer (score 0):

You need a few things:

1. Make sure to move the `highest` variable outside the loop. If not, it would be replaced each time the loop runs, and you never find out what is the highest value in your list.
2. And the second, which might not be completely necessary in your case, but it might be helpful, is to use `float("-inf")` as the first assigning value to the `highest` variable. This makes sure that you have not ignored any element in your list (there might have been negative values in the list, too)
3. Make sure that `return` is out of the `for` loop and at the end of the function.

Here is what I have come up with:

```py
my_list = [1, 3, 5, 6, 10, 40, 2, 3, 9, 80, 23, 22]

def multiplied128 ():
  highest = float("-inf")
  for num in my_list:
    val = num # This is not necessary. You can simply replace `num` with `val` in the for loop itself.
    ans = val*128
    if ans > highest:
         highest = ans
  return(highest)

print(multiplied128())
```

##### Output

```
10240
```

The output is as it should be: The highest value in your list is 80. Mutliplying this number by 128 results in 10240.